# Do I really need Crashlytics integration when appstoreconnect is providing the crashlogs?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, crashlytics, testflight

I am about to publish my app to App Store. It is still in beta testing phase on TestFlight.
I observed that the App Store connect was able to provide the crashlogs of the app. So when appstoreconnect is able to provide the crashlogs, do I really need to integrate Crashlytics? What will be the advantage if I do?

Will I still be able to view the crashlogs on appstoreconnect after the app is released onto appstore?

The logs I got from appstoreconnect are symbolicated. Is it because I published an app in debug mode? Will I get the symbolicated crashlogs if I publish the app in release mode?

Comment: One of the benefits of using something Crashlytics, is they will automatically symbolise the crash reports - which is a real time saver.  They can also provide a decent amount of metrics about the devices in use and the frequency of errors, so you can spend your time on the most prevalent of issues.

Comment: There are tons of advantages to using Crashlytics, but the one I would probably callout the most is that you are guaranteed to receive crash reports from your user base, whereas with the App Store, there's a good chance your users won't always opt to send you their crash data.